# Don't let me change the css Google Chart

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I have a table made with Google Chart that I've added styles to. The problem is that my `padding` style has less priority than the style from google's stylesheet.

What is `.google-visualization-table-table *{}`? Where does it come from?

A picture is worth a thousand words. > https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfhkY.jpg

Here's the code as well:

```
.google-visualization-table-table ) {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2px;
}

// and my style code:
.tableHeaderCell {
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0.75em 1.5em; // this is the line of code that doesnt overwrite the pre-existing padding of 2px;
}
```

html:  `<td class="tableHeaderCell google-visualization-table-sorthdr"></td>`

Comment: Pictures are worth a thousand words to those not on work networks with imgur blocked. Please describe it anyway. Also, you seem to have accidentally a few words when you ask "Where does?" in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always add `!important` to override the `.google-visualization-table-table` code by doing:

```
.tableHeaderCell {
   //other css styles here;
   padding: 0.75em 1.5em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the priority of CSS rule, I think you should try :

```
.google-vizualisation-table-table .tableHeaderCell{
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
}
```